# Get Website Listed in Google News

Tags: wordpress, google-news

I've developed a wordpress website and with the help of Yoast News SEO plugin, I've created the News Sitemap XML.
However, when I submit the Sitemap to Google Webmasters, I get an error as below

> Your Sitemap is on a site that is not in the Google News database. Google News can only accept Sitemaps from sites that we crawl. If your site is crawled by Google News, please check that the URL of your Sitemap agrees with the URLs of your articles as they appear on Google News, including any leading "www". If you would like to request inclusion of your site in Google News, please contact the Google News support team.

It links to [this page](https://www.google.com/support/news/bin/static.py?page=contact_policy.cs&hl=en).

There are no instructions on that page to request inclusion in Google News.

I need to know where to request inclusion so that my website shows up in Google News.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs at [webmasters.se] or [webapps.se].


Answer (score 2):

You need to apply your site for Google News inclusion using the following form:

- https://support.google.com/news/publisher/troubleshooter/3179220?#ts=3179198

Reference: [**Getting into Google News**](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40787?hl=en)